# How to place multiple string variables in one coordinate of an 3d-array?

Tags: java

For a school project i have to make a birthday callender in java. In this callender you can add, remove, and change peoples birthdays. My idea was to make a 3d-array which includes 12 months of 31 days, and an arraylist in each day since an unknown amount of people can have the same birthday. I have no idea how i can store multiple names in a day, and how to store strings and ints in this 3d-array of type int. Can someone help me please?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.Month;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class verjaardag {

    public static void optionChoice() {
        System.out.println("1 Verjaardag toevoegen,");
        System.out.println("2 Verjaardag verwijderen,");
        System.out.println("3 Alle verjaardagen zien");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<String> namen = new ArrayList<>();
        int birthday[][] = new int[12][31]; 



        System.out.println("Verjaardagskalender 0.1");
        optionChoice();


        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Kies uit de volgende nummers 1, 2, 3!");
            String choice = scanner.nextLine();


            if (choice.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Wie is er jarig?");
                String name = scanner.next();
                namen.add(name);

                System.out.println("Op welke dag?");
                int day = scanner.nextInt();


                System.out.println("Van welke maand?");
                int month = scanner.nextInt();


                birthday [month -1] [day -1] = namen;

            }

            if (choice.equals("2")) {

            }

            if (choice.equals("3")) {

                for (String allList : namen) {
                    System.out.println(allList);
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is better solved using classes that you need to create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> ArrayList<String> namen = new ArrayList<>();
> int birthday[][] = new int[12][31];
> ```

Think about it; this just does not make sense. You want 1 list of names **for each date**, not 'one list of names for the entire app'. The 'thing' you want for each date is not 'a number' (`int`, that's a number), but you want 'a list of names'.

Thus, what you're looking for is:

```
List<String>[][] = new ArrayList<String>[12][31];
```

except that doesn't compile, as you immediately run into a problem here: Generics and arrays don't work well together.

Arrays are annoying constructs that break the language and have a crap API. That's okay - as long as you realize what they are for: They are low-level constructs you use only when building, say, a graphics driver. Or, heh, the code that powers `ArrayList`. Especially when the 'type' of the array is not primitive, you should probably not be using it at all.

You can instead of a list of months. A month is then represented as a list of days, and a day is represented as a list of names.

`List<List<List<String>>>` is what you then end up with.

This gets unwieldy, and fast. It's debatable whether this is the right data-type in the first place. Perhaps instead you can encode a day: `(month -1) * 31 + (date - 1)`, this gets you a number between 0 (for jan 1st) and 371 for December 31st. Now you can just use `List<List<String>>` instead. Or better yet, `Map<Integer, String>`. Java works better if you actually let the type system work for you. That date ID should be a class, so that it can have a nice toString for example (given such an ID, you can just call `.getMonth()`, instead of doing the math (`(idNum)/31 + 1`).

That's perhaps a spoiler / coming attractions: A level of java you haven't achieved yet.

You can just use a `for` loop to set up a list to be initialized to the right size:

```
List<List<List<String>>> days = new ArrayList<>();
for (int month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
  List<List<String>> monthList = new ArrayList<>();
  days.add(monthList);
  for (int day = 0; day < 31; day++) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    monthList.add(names);
  }
}
```

This also creates a list for the non-existent dates (such as feb 31st), but this doesn't appear to be an actual problem.

To be clear, don't ever do this in a 'real' app, types like `List<List<List<String>>>` are a pretty clear indication the app is badly written. This is a job for `Map<DayOfYear, List<Person>>` or something similar. You'd be using `List<List<List<String>>>` solely because you haven't gotten around to maps and making your own types yet. Or if you are, then do the `Map` thing instead :)